# What is `rake test` doing before running tests, and why does it take so long?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testunit

I have a rails app with about 40 tests using the default rails test:unit. The tests themselves run quickly, but there is a delay of about 8 seconds where `rake test` seems to be doing something in the background, and then the tests are run.

I am using linux to run the tests.

What is happening in this time after `rake test` is called, but before the tests run? Is there a way to reduce or eliminate this wait time?

Here is a [screenr video](http://screenr.com/B4C7) to illuminate the question. The time in question is 0:04 - 0:11.

Comment: The more code in your app and the more gems it uses the longer it takes to boot rails, i beleive using rake to run your tests will boot rails twice, once in rake file and then again in the test helper; i tend to use rspec - 'bundle exec rspec spec' and bypass rake, you can probably do similiar with minitest?

Comment: You can use Spork https://github.com/sporkrb/spork to avoid loading the Rails environment for each test run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's loading the rails environment (running your initializers, loading your models and controllers, etc).  I find this to be aggravatingly slow, particularly on Windows machines, and especially on jRuby (which has to start up the JVM as well).

There *are* ways to speed up jRuby, listed [here](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/PerformanceTuning), but ruby on Windows still seems to be very slow compared to OSX or linux.

Edit: just saw your video.  You're waiting less than 10 seconds.  Compared to the 20+ seconds I get on Windows machines that's not so bad.